# while loop repeated last row in array from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch all rows from my mysql table which is matched with my query
as of now I have two rows with matched query I am saving every row in 
`$tourData` variable and than adding into `$allTourData` variable in while loop.

This function returns two arrays in my `$allTourData` but instead getting first row and second row I am getting second row two time.

here is my code.

```
public static function getTourAvailabilityStatus($date, $route)
{
    $lt   = MySQL::connect();
    $tour = $lt->prepare
    (   /** @lang MySQL */
        "
            SELECT id, token, route, date, travels_name, bus_number, st, aj, wt, sl
            FROM tour
            WHERE date = ? AND route = ? ;
            "
        );

    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->bind_param('ss', $date, $route);
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->execute();
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tourData = [];
    $tour->bind_result(
        $tourData['id'], $tourData['token'], $tourData['route'], $tourData['date'], $tourData['travelsName'],
        $tourData['BusNumber'], $tourData['st'], $tourData['aj'], $tourData['wt'], $tourData['sl']
    );
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $allTourData = [];
    while($tour->fetch())
    {
        $allTourData[] = $tourData;
    }
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->close();

    return $allTourData;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
public static function getTourAvailabilityStatus($date, $route)
{
    $lt   = MySQL::connect();
    $tour = $lt->prepare
    (   /** @lang MySQL */
        "
            SELECT id, token, route, date, travels_name, bus_number, st, aj, wt, sl
            FROM tour
            WHERE date = ? AND route = ? ;
            "
        );

    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->bind_param('ss', $date, $route);
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->execute();
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);

    $tour->bind_result(
        $id, $token, $route, $date, $travelsName,$BusNumber, $st, $aj, $wt, $sl
    );
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $allTourData = [];
    while($tour->fetch())
    {
        $allTourData[] = [ $id, $token, $route, $date, $travelsName,$BusNumber, $st, $aj, $wt, $sl];
    }
    MySQL::error($tour, $lt);
    $tour->close();

    return $allTourData;
}
```

Comment: I have tired this but this changes my preassigned `$tourData` variable to 1 where I have data of my rows.

Comment: Yes, This works like charm, After spending 2 hours on this now I know never ever assign bind_result param's in a array when you need multi rows form table :)